# Add columns of two rows based on a condition in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table structure:

```
+------+-------+-------+--------+
| mid  | a     | b     | points |
+------+-------+-------+--------+
|   69 |  3137 | 13316 |    210 |
|   70 | 13316 |  3137 |    350 |
|   71 |  3497 | 13316 |    200 |
|   72 | 13316 |  3497 |     25 |
|   73 |  3605 | 13316 |    205 |
|   74 | 13316 |  3605 |    290 |
+------+-------+-------+--------+
```

I want to add the "points" values of two rows when "a" of row 1 = "b" of row 2 and "a" of row 2 = "b" of row 1.

The output needs to be something like this:

```
+------+-------+-------+--------+
| mid  | a     | b     | points |
+------+-------+-------+--------+
|   69 |  3137 | 13316 |    560 |
|   71 |  3497 | 13316 |    225 |
|   73 |  3605 | 13316 |    495 |
+------+-------+-------+--------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try it this way

```sql
SELECT t1.mid, t1.a, t1.b, t1.points + t2.points points
  FROM table1 t1 JOIN table1 t2
    ON t1.a = t2.b
   AND t1.b = t2.a
   AND t1.mid < t2.mid
```

or leveraging MySQL non-standard `GROUP BY` extension

```sql
SELECT mid, a, b, SUM(points) points
  FROM
(
  SELECT mid, a, b, points
    FROM table1
   ORDER BY mid
) q
 GROUP BY LEAST(a, b), GREATEST(a, b)
```

Output:

```
| MID |    A |     B | POINTS |
|-----|------|-------|--------|
|  69 | 3137 | 13316 |    560 |
|  71 | 3497 | 13316 |    225 |
|  73 | 3605 | 13316 |    495 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/108cc/5)** demo

Comment: Thanks a lot peterm:) This exactly wat I was looking for.  You saved lot of my time and appreciate the prompt reply.

Comment: One more questions,  can u look at this link, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aa462/1.  I have changed the schema slightly.  I want to make sure that 13316 is always in column "b".  Can you help me here.

Comment: Oh ok.. so the key is using LEAST and GREATEST functions.  Ok I get the point.  I can work with this.  Great help! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood correctly then you want:

```
SELECT p1.mid, p1.a, p1.b, p1.points + p2.points points
FROM points p1 
INNER JOIN points  p2 ON p1.a = p2.b  AND p1.b = p2.a
WHERE p1.mid < p2.mid
```

I have knocked it up in [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/47d20/4) and gives the output that you want.

Comment: Got the solution Kevin.  Thanks for your response.